# Every simply connected space is contractible

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

this is a topology question:

> True or false: Every simply connected space is contractible

I think it's false, and I saw the counterexample of $S^n$, however the knowledge to show that it is not contractible is (using homology) beyond my course.

Could you provide a counterexample to this statement, and also gives a proof of why it is not contractible?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you familiar with (higher) homotopy groups?  $\pi_2$, $\pi_3$, ...?

Comment: This will be a hard task if you literally do not know any other algebraic topology invariants other than simple connectivity. But having said that, one can use degree theory, from differential topology, to prove that $S^2$ (and $S^n$ in general for $n \ge 2$) is not contractible. A proof like that requires you to know certain approximation theorems: every continuous function $S^2 \to S^2$ can be approximated by a smooth function; every homotopy between smooth functions can be approximated by a smooth homotopy; then you have to build up degree theory from there.

Comment: @EricTowers  Yes, I know its definition, but not familiar enough to see how this will solve my problem... Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Liz I just checked your profile and you are asking LOTS of questions in a very short amount of time and it seems that you didn't solve any on your own (using the hints we gave you). Also, the type of questions you are asking do very much look like homework. Are you just copy pasting your homework here on stackexchange?

Comment: @noctusraid Hi, no, these are quiz problems that we've done in class. But we only need to show true or false instead of justify it. So sometimes I 'guess' it correctly, but don't understand why it is... And I don't want to still have the old unanswered questions in my head before a new lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the homotopy groups of a contractible space are trivial (because all the homotopy groups of the point you're contracting to are trivial).  Consequently, if any $\pi_i \not\cong \{0\}$, your space is not contractible.  For all $n > 0$, $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  This is a standard fact, and you can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#General_theory).  (This is proved using [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_map) theory.)  In fact, that $\pi_i(S^n)$ is frequently nontrivial for $i > n > 1$ is a wide area of study.

If you are familiar with homology, you could use the standard fact $H_0(S^n) \cong H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and the remaining homology groups are trivial.  This is normally shown applying the [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) to the above results on homotopy groups and the fact that $S^n$ is $(n-1)$-connected.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this property, we only mentioned the fact that $\pi_i(S^n)$  is trivial, but it's good to know.